# TCP "Remote Host closed connection"

Tags: c#, python, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi

Don't know if this is more realted to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but here's my problem anyway:

I wrote a tcp server with Python for Raspberry Pi and a client with C# for a any Windows based PC. I first tested it my main PC through router and everything was working fine. Then I changed the server side (Pi) to host its own access point where everyone can connect.

I tested that with a EeePC running Win 7 Ultimate (Intel Atom, veeeeery slow) and it worked. Problems started when I moved the client software to that mini laptop; tried to connect to the server, connects normally, but when client starts to send it says "The remote host has closed the connection" (or something like that, I'm using Finnish OS).

I immediately thought that it has something to do with the Pi's access point so I connected my mini laptop to my router and tried to connect to my main PC, same thing. Then I started to worry if my client software is broken, but I took one last test and tried to connect with my main PC to the mini laptop and this time, no errors, only VERY slow connection (at least I think so, because only part of my controls went through with ultimate latency).

So where is the problem? The mini laptop aka EeePC or what? Why does it say that the remote host disconnected?

**EDIT:**
I founded a nano USB Wi-Fi dongle and plugged that to my main PC and then connected to Pi's access point with it. Everything worked like a charm, there was no latency at all.

It must be the mini laptop, so I give some specs:
Just installed clean copy of Win 7 Ultimate with no firewall, antivirus or anything. Installed only Service Pack 1 and Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013. Drivers are Windows default.

Comment: Did you capture the traffic with Wireshark (or any other network sniffer)?

Comment: @matcheek Nope, not even sure how to do that... I edited my post, read it again if it helps to track the problem.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)